# Nested formula with countif

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to create a monthly filter option on a speadsheet for my boss.  The overview spreadsheet consist of countif formulas. My boss would like me to add a filter, where he can enter July or 7(yellow cell) to get the data filtered to that month. Is there a nested formula within excel to do this? I am unfamiliar with nested formulas.

[Data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGz7n.jpg)

[Overview worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ehUj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use pivot tables.

1) Select all your data with the headers

2) Go to the insert tab and click pivot table (just click ok for now)

3) Drag whatever values you want counts for into the rows section
    In this case drag down the dates for example

4)Next drag whatever you want to perform an action on into the values box...in this case since we want to count how many instances of a single date or month occur, we drag this down into the box.

5)In the dropdown menu for the values, change it to count.

6) Done

You can create your entire overview sheet using this single pivot table and not a single formula. Hope that helps.